# How to use iframe in liferay portlet?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, iframe, liferay

Currently I am working on liferay 6.0

In my project I need to show a page in iframe. I have added iframe in my jsf page. When user request that jsf page whole page works fine but that iframe doesnt show respective page. Except that it shows that page not found and in console side gives message Current URL generates exception:null.

Please somedbody tell me how can I use iframe in portlet.

Comment: `<iframe>` is a HTML element nothing to do with any of the portal technology or JSP or JSF. It would be better to paste some code and the `src` attribute you are using in iframe

Comment: @PrakashK <iframe src="abcd.xhtml" width="100%" height="300">
     </iframe>
This is how I have put my iframe.

Comment: Can you get to the `abcd.xhtml` from the browser address-bar? Put some liferay URL or a full complete URL like `http://example.com` inside the `src`, and that would give you an idea as to what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You should set the URL of the desired JSF page as the `src` of the `iframe`, and set the `iframe` as the content of the portlet.